# Connection to internet without port forwarding

Tags: networking, linux

I want to access RPi from Internet without port Forwarding. Is there any way to do it? if yes, then how many and how to implement them?

Comment: Can you edit the question with what you have tried?

Answer (score 4):

The Raspberry Pi Foundation blog currently lists [two alternatives to port forwarding](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/) for communicating with a Pi over the internet:

> **remot3.it**
>
> One secure alternative to port forwarding is [remot3.it](https://www.remot3.it/), by Weaved,
>   Inc. remot3.it ("remote it") is software you install on your Raspberry
>   Pi to access a single Pi, or manage a large number of Pis, from
>   anywhere over the internet. Use remot3.it to access any TCP port on
>   your Pi over the web including SSH, VNC, HTTP(S), RDP, and custom TCP
>   services.
>
> [How to get started with remot3.it for Pi](http://forum.weaved.com/t/how-to-get-started-with-remot3-it-for-pi/1029)
>
> ...
>
> **Dataplicity**
>
> [Dataplicity](https://dataplicity.com/) allows you to connect and control your Pi's shell remotely
>   from a web browser and its mobile apps. You can use Dataplicity's
>   Wormhole feature to host a website or API directly from your Pi, and
>   automatically enable HTTPS/SSL with no configuration or certificates.
>
> It uses WebSockets over HTTPS to provide a connection, and requires a
>   single-line install.
>
> [Getting started with Dataplicity](https://docs.dataplicity.com/docs/getting-started-with-dataplicity)

Comment: What about other devices?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by other devices. Can you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

It has [recently been announced](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/get-back-to-my-pi-from-anywhere-with-vnc-connect/) that RealVNC are now letting Pi users use their VNC Connect service to connect to Pi's that are running behind a firewall.  This gives the user access to the GUI running on the Pi. It is just a matter of enabling the service, creating a RealVNC account, and logging into the account both on the Pi and the computer you want to connect to the pi from.  Full instructions are available in the [RealVNC docs](https://www.realvnc.com/docs/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-setup)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a free service like [PiTunnel.com](https://www.pitunnel.com) to access your Raspberry Pi remotely.

Super simple to set up, and you get remote terminal, status monitoring, and tunnels to things like web server and vnc. No port forwarding or router configuration required.

(Full disclosure, I'm the creator of PiTunnel and we created it specifically to solve this problem for ourselves and others looking to do the same thing)